# exe stopped running error in setting up MySQL C++ connector on Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

We tried running the following code to connect database:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>

using namespace sql;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    sql::Driver *driver;

    cout << "TEST1" << endl;

    driver = get_driver_instance();

    cout << "TEST2" << endl;

    con = driver->connect("TCP:://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "");

    cout << "TEST3" << endl;

}
```

After building the program successfully, we ran it and encountered the following pop-up message:

"mysql_demo.exe stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program."

TEST1 and TEST2 are printed successfully on the console, but TEST3 is not.

The platform we use is Windows. We have set up includes and libraries such as mysql server, mysql c++ connector and boost.

I was wondering what the message could indicate. Could anyone help?

Comment: What is `driver`? Where do you declare it? Is it perhaps `NULL`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste that line of code. Now it is added. Thanks for pointing it out! Yes, it is likely that "driver" is NULL. If so, does it mean some compatible issues with the mysql libraries?

Comment: The 'driver' is not 'NULL'. I'm able to call 'getMajorVersion()', 'getMinorVersion()' and 'getPatchVersion()' functions, but not the 'connect()' and 'getName()' functions.